# Implementation of Marketing Cloud from Scratch

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I am new to marketing cloud. Could anyone help me to provide insights on how to implement marketing cloud from scratch?

TIA

Answer (score 6):

Please understand that Marketing Cloud is an enterprise-level platform. You should not implement it without prior experience. Without an understanding of the platforms data models and core functionality, you can severely compromise the implementation architecture and worse still, send messages to wrong individuals or audiences.

The [implementation guides](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_implementation_guides.htm&type=5) are helpful, but really serve as a checklist for implementation, and do not constitute a comprehensive implementation manual.

I would recommend that anyone who is implementing this platform has attained the Marketing Cloud Consultant certification and has previous hands-on experience. If you don't, then I'd recommend you find a Salesforce Partner with Marketing Cloud experience. Visit [Salesforce Consultants page](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/consulting) and filter your results by 'Marketing Cloud' in the left pane.

Many of these partners would be able to assist you in the implementation, or guide you through the implementation process.